# ios uiview subviews-loaded-event

Tags: ios, uiview, subview

Is there an easy way to know when all the `subivews` have loaded?

Right now I'm doing:

```
if([[self subviews] count] == 10) {
    //do stuff
}
```

If there isn't an event/method for this, is there at least a way to dynamically know what the child count is GOING to be?

## edit

I re-read this just now and realize it's a bit *asinine*. Let me clarify:

I'm loading this `UIView` from a `XIB` file and I wanted to know when the `NIB` has officially loaded (with all of it's children). So I dare say the correct answer would be `awakeFromNib`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're calling this from a viewController, just use

```
-(void)viewDidLoad;
```

Which is called after the view and all its subviews are loaded. If you're doing it from one of the views inside the nib, use:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib;
```

Which is called after the view's subviews have been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding subviews programmatically (e.g. `[myView addSubview:anotherView]`), then of course there is no way to know; the program could add more subviews at any time, if you write it that way.

If you are loading the view from a nib, you are probably looking for the `awakeFromNib` method.  From the [*NSObject UIKit Additions Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an `awakeFromNib` message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an `awakeFromNib` message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.